# How to convert VTK Structured point file to OpenVDB

Tags: vtk, converters, openvdb

I'm trying to render a [VTK](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK) file containing a structured point data array into blender 3D.
I've found an addon ([BVTKnodes](https://bvtknodes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)) allowing to import VTK files and extract iso surfaces from them, but here I would like to do a volumetric rendering.

Since blender can only handle OpenVDB files for volumetric input, I'm looking for a way to convert my VTK file into the OpenVDB format.

What would be the best option here ?

Thanks !